# Create SharePoint 2013 search Result Blocks programmatically

Tags: c#, search, sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2013

I am are trying to create Result Blocks through powershell (or c#).

It is easy to do this through UI in Central Admin or on a site collection, but I want to automate the process through PowerShell (or in a feature receiver).

Have searched the Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration API, but haven't found any add or create methods for creating Result Blocks.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Regards Osmund